# Is it possible to send a secure (signed) request to an Amazon API gateway using C#?

Tags: c#, aws-api-gateway

I would like to make use of Amazon API Gateway and the security and throttling features that are advertised.

Is is possible to access them from a C# application?

At present, the only way I can see to make a secure, signed request (using the AWS Signature version 4) is to use the SDK/librariess generated by Amazon itself - which seems to be limited to javascript, ios and Android versions.

Is it possible to make a request using other methods?

Any information about how to make a connection from a desktop Java application or C# application would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`API Gateway` requests are normal requests to `RESTful API`. You should deploy your API and then create an `Access Key` in the dashboard and assign this key to your deployment. You can then use this `Access Key` in the `X-Api-Key` header so the server can `authorize` your `HTTP Requests`.

Here's more information on how to [Create and use API Keys for Amazon API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html).

If you're looking to `authorize and authenticate` your users, then you need to use both, the `X-Api-Key` and `SigV4 request signing` using `IAM Credentials` as described in various `AWS` documents. Ideally you generate `API Gateway SDK` for your `API` and observe it's functionality. There's also a nice example project [Secure Pet Store](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store) describing how to use `IAM Credentials` from `Cognito` to `authorize and authenticate` and possibly `invoke Lambda using caller credentials`.

Comment: The ``X-Api-Key`` header is used to include API keys created in the API Gateway into your request  but these API keys are really intended for user tracking and rate limiting.  API keys do not provide any request signing or real security for the requests.  To get real SigV4 request signing, you need to create a client library in the language you want to use that uses the access_key, secret_key, and session_token associated with an account to cryptographically sign the requests.

Comment: To add reference to what @garnaat says, from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) (see bottom) it says: "For user authentication and authorization, don't use API keys. Use an IAM role, a Lambda authorizer, or an Amazon Cognito user pool." API keys are used to throttle and monitor usage, not for authorization.

Comment: @JohnLee Thanks for pointing that out, however it does not apply in every scenario. I'll consider updating the answer.